# PID Controller in Keil Uvision4

Tags: c, keil, pid-controller

How to implement a PID controller in Keil Uvision 4?. I am currently working on a code that runs the PID with the the help of a water tank system. I am new to this keil Uvision4. Can someone guide me through this please? I have created a PID controller code in normal c using Dev C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on how to create a PID controller [here](http://www.hitex.com/fileadmin/img/download/Basic_DC_Motor_Speed_PID_Control_With_The_Infineon_C167_Family.pdf). Keil support actually pointed at this document when [someone asked the same question at their forum](http://www.keil.com/forum/3/).
Code was written using Keil [C166 C compiler](http://www.keil.com/c166/c166.asp) and [uVision](http://www.keil.com/uvision/) IDE.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did check on the sites that you have provided. It is useful in some parts. But what I am looking for is for a basic code of PID on a water tank. It has been done in matlab. But I have to do it in keil uVision 4.